# Why is Apache 2.4 running as the local user instead of www-data?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apache2.4

I installed Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 from ppa:ondrej.
I have the expected:  /etc/apache2/envvars
I have the expected:  /etc/init.d/apache2
I even hard coded in: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
User www-data
Group www-data

I log in with user "demo" and type:

## sudo service apache2 start

And then:

## ps aux | grep apache2

This is what I see:

## demo  31462  0.0  0.0   6504   620 pts/1    S+   10:56   0:00 grep apache2

I WANT to run as www-data!
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your ps output is showing your grep command, not any httpd process.  You must have a startup failure if it's the only process with "apache2" in it. Check your logs, and use apachectl/apachectl -t while debugging.